# How to center a javascript popup window with the code I already have

Tags: javascript, popup, window, center

I need to be able to center the popup window that appears. I know this has been asked many times but I couldn't find one that worked. Please help!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
       jQuery('.open-window').click(function () {
            var NWin = window.open(jQuery(this).prop('href'), '', 'scrollbars=1,height=400,width=400');
                  if (window.focus) {
                      NWin.focus();
                  }
                  return false;
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (jQuery) {
    var screenWidth = (screen.width-400)/2,
        screenHeight = (screen.height-400)/2;

jQuery('.open-window').click(function () {
    var NWin = window.open(jQuery(this).prop('href'), '', "'scrollbars=1, height=400, width=400, top="+screenHeight+", left="+screenWidth+"'");

    if (window.focus) {
        NWin.focus();
    }
    return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/cesitun/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thank you! Worked Perfectly!